# How to make it so that it sends out the pdf only after the pdf is generated using async await

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, pdf-generation, sendmail

How to make the mail transporter to wait until the pdf is generated?

I attached the code that I have tried. My browser hangs and failed to send out the email. The issue is that the mail transporter tries to send out email before the pdf is generated. I am guessing that I did not use the async and await at the right place.

```
      async () => {
        await pdf.create(document, options).then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })

        let message = "Testing"

        let mailOptions = {
          from: "xxx@gmail.com",
          to: "yyy@gmail.com",
          subject: 'Subject testing',
          text: message,
          attachments: [{
            path: __dirname + '/../public/reports/' + 'test.pdf',
          }]
        }

        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log("sent email")
            res.json({
              email: "sent"
            });
          }
        })
      }
```

Comment: You can only `await` a promise.  You need to use promises.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. The await in the transporter.sendMail is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't call the function so the operation is not being executed. I removed the await in the transporter.sendMail because it is not doing anything.

```
  sendPDF();
  async function sendPDF() {
    await pdf.create(document, options).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })

    let message = "Testing"

    let mailOptions = {
      from: "xxx@gmail.com",
      to: "yyy@gmail.com",
      subject: 'Subject testing',
      text: message,
      attachments: [{
        path: __dirname + '/../public/reports/' + 'test.pdf',
      }]
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("sent email")
        res.json({
          email: "sent"
        });
      }
    })
  }
```